# CakePHP 3 - Admin Routing to Plugin Not Working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am creating a plugin that I want integrated within the admin section of my application. My application structure for the admin section looks like this:

```
src/Controller/Admin/AdminsController.php
src/Controller/Admin/ProductsController.php
src/Controller/Admin/BlogsController.php
```

`AdminsController.php` looks like this:

```
namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\Network\Exception\ForbiddenException;

class AdminsController extends AppController{
```

And my Admin controllers, ie `BlogsController.php` looks like this:

```
namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use App\Controller\Admin\AdminsController;

class BlogsController extends AdminsController {
```

My plugin has a `FeedbacksController` that looks just like the Blogs Controller above, which also uses `AdminsController` from the application: `plugin/AkkaFeedback/src/Controller/Admin/FeedbacksController.php`

```
namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use App\Controller\Admin\AdminsController;

class FeedbacksController extends AdminsController {`
```

Also, within my plugin I have `plugin/AkkaFeedback/src/Controller/FeedbacksController.php`

My Intention is to have `/admin/feedbacks` point to this controller. Is this even possible within CakePHP? I have tried many possibilities without success. Here is what I have tried as well as others without success:

```
Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Dashboards', 'action' => 'index']);

    $routes->connect('/feedbacks', ['plugin' => 'AkkaFeedback', 'controller' => 'Feedbacks', 'action' => 'index']);

    // I have tried this
    //$routes->connect('/feedbacks', ['plugin' => 'AkkaFeedback', 'controller' => 'Feedbacks', 'action' => 'index', 'prefix' => 'admin']); // I have also tried this

    // And this without succcess
    // /admin/akka_feedback/feedbacks
    // $routes->plugin('AkkaFeedback', function ($routes) {
    //    $routes->connect('/:controller');
    // });

    $routes->fallbacks('InflectedRoute');
});
```

The error I get is: `Controller class Feedbacks could not be found.`, but there is a Feedbacks class, both in `Controller` and `Controller/Admin` within the plugin.

Not sure what else to try. Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more researching I was able to make it work by adding the following to the plugin's routes.php file `plugins/AkkaFeedback/config/routes.php`:

```
Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
    $routes->plugin('AkkaFeedback', function ($routes) {
        $routes->connect('/:controller', ['action' => 'index'], ['routeClass' => 'DashedRoute']);
        $routes->connect('/:controller/:action/*', [], ['routeClass' => 'DashedRoute']);
    });
});
```

In conjunction with the routes added to the routes.php file of the application.`config/routes.php`

```
Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Dashboards', 'action' => 'index']);
    $routes->connect('/feedbacks', ['plugin' => 'AkkaFeedback', 'controller' => 'Feedbacks', 'action' => 'index']);
    $routes->connect('/feedbacks/:action/*', ['plugin' => 'AkkaFeedback', 'controller' => 'Feedbacks']);

    $routes->fallbacks('InflectedRoute');
});
```

I am not sure if this is the best way, but it works for now.

Comment: Thats how I made it work for [me](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-sandbox/blob/3.0/plugins/Sandbox/config/routes.php) as well.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Wished I had come across your process before. It would have saved me a few hours of headache. :)

Comment: In addition to these routes changes, I had to make some changes to my composer.json file. [See Cookbook section on Autoloading Plugin Classes](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#autoloading-plugin-classes)

Answer (score 2):

Your `FeebacksController namespace declaration` isn't correct. It should be:

```
namespace AkkaFeedback\Controller\Admin;

use App\Controller\Admin\AdminsController;

class FeebacksController extends AdminsController {`
```

Comment: Thanks for that! This somewhat works, but I now encounter a different routing issue. I get the following error: `A route matching "array ( 'controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'plugin' => 'AkkaFeedback', '_ext' => NULL, )" could not be found. `. It seems that it has something to do with permission, however for testing I have added `$this->Auth->allow();` to the `beforeFilter()`, but still the same problem occurs.

Comment: @AndreS that auth error is because the auth component is trying to redirect to the login page, and your `loginAction` key probably doesn't specifically say *not* to use a plugin. Check out http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html (search loginAction)

Comment: @jeremyharris Thanks for your input. I suspected it was because of that, although I was specifically telling the Application not to care who accesses that plugin's controller with `$this->Auth->allow()`. It turned out, the application was redirecting even before it got to controller because my routes were not setup correctly. All good now!

Answer (score 1):

In `config/routes.php`:

```
Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});
```

In `plugins/CustomPlugin/config/routes.php`:

```
Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
    $routes->plugin('CustomPlugin', ['path' => '/custom-plugin'], function ($routes) {
        $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
    });
});
```

It seems the best method and it works properly.
In this way i can have an Admin section in the root project and also in the plugin.